# How can I pass a ViewBag from controller to View(Ajax Url)

Tags: javascript, c#, json, viewbag

** Controller Code **

I have the below code in my `Controller` and the method `get_curent_LoanNumber`

```
public JsonResult (string loan_code)
{
    try
    {
        using (sqlConnection)
        {
            dynamic loanno = sqlConnection.Query("get_loan_number", new {loan_code }, 
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();

            ViewBag.currentLoanNumbe= loanno.LoanNo;

            return Json(loanno, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**View Code**
This is the code in the `View`, the `JavaScript` function `savePayslipInfo` makes the `Ajax` request.

```
 function () {

    console.log('@ViewBag.currentLoanNumbe');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:1079/loanapplication/save_Payslip_Info/?loan_no" + '@ViewBag.currentLoanNumbe',
        data: {
            //loan_no: $(loan_no).val(),
            basic_salary: $("#basic_salary").val(),
            house_allowance: $("#house_allowance").val(),
            other_allowance: $("#other_allowance").val(),
            other_payment: $("#other_payment").val(),
            total_deduction: $("#total_deduction").val()
        },
        success: function () {
            $('#msg').html("Payslip info saved successfully").fadeIn('slow');
            $('#msg').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you are returning JSON, you need to **not** use the `ViewBag`. Instead, the data you want **must be in the JSON payload itself**. So incorporate it into `loanno`.

Comment: Your viewbag contains  values from loanno. But you're already returning loanno to the AJAX call, so the viewbag doesn't contain any information you haven't already provided. You don't need it. And it makes no sense either...viewbag is used when you return a view, but here you're returning JSON, not a view.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how MVC works. You are not returning a view from your action method. You are returning a JSON. So there is no view that gets rendered tied to the action method. What you are essentially doing is using the action method as an API and calling it from Javascript using AJAX which is not the same as returning and binding a view from action. Your ViewBag won't be accessible because the View you are using here is not being rendered by the Action method in the question.

Comment: So in this case how am i going to achieve my objective?,@Shahzad

Comment: @CheruiyotAKirui Either you pass the data along with the JSON you are returning, or let the action return a View and then you can use the Viebbag and the value there

Comment: I dont want my page reloaded and as you see am already returning loanno in json. Which gives me the result so my issue is when I am in the second tab I want to use the loanno returned(It is in the partial View) to insert data to another table. So I was trying to use Viewbag which I thiught it will still hold my value.

Comment: @CheruiyotAKirui `ViewBag` is **per http request** so `I thiught it will still hold my value` is not true. It won't hold it.

Comment: @CheruiyotAKirui What you can do is to load your main page by returning a view. Have a Viewbag return your data if you want. Then load your tabs data for all tabs using AJAX and returnning JSON from Action methods. That way your base action that returns a view can pass you the data, i.e. loand number and you would not have to reload your page on tab switch.